# Setting up SFTP Sever for Java client to allow downloads with public key only

Tags: java, sftp, public-key-encryption, ftp-client, openssh

I want to setup Secure FTP Server with public and private key cryptography.  A Java program will upload and download files from this server.  Do I need to have two pairs of keys one for upload and one for upload and one for download?

I need to support two operations.

1. Java client (Private key)  ----------------- Upload File ----------- Server(Public Key) Keys generated on client
2. Java client(Public Key)-------------------- Download File --------- Server(Private Key) Keys generated on server

Can it be done using the single pair of keys?

Comment: why would you need to introduce a second pair? also this problem is solved already with sftp i ftps protocols

Answer (score 0):

*First, you probably mean SFTP, not Secure FTP (FTPS).*

---

You seem to misunderstand how a public key authentication in FTPS works.

You cannot do anything with the public key only. You always need the private key too. Even for downloads. Any SFTP session is bi-directional. You always need to send *something* to the server (the SFTP/SSH requests at least), and they need to be encrypted with the private key.

---

To answer your question: Yes, you need two keypairs. Or rather you need two SFTP/SSH accounts.

---

To do with the public key only for download, you will need to use plain FTP and use the keypairs for encrypting/decrypting the files only. But that's not SFTP anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The connection is bidirectional - you can upload and download as much as you like with the single connection.

Having said that, there are two keypairs in the one connection: the client's and the server's. The server presents its public key to the client to validate that you're talking to the correct server. The client public key gets added to the list of authorized keys on the server.